# Does Mathematica take advantage of hyper-threading (if it is available)?

Tags: parallelization

I do not know much about computer architecture, but some Intel processors have [hyper-threading technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading), which can apparently improve parallelization for applications that take advantage of it.  In a processor with hyper-threading technology, the number of threads is usually twice the number of cores -- whereas in a processor *without* hyper-threading, the number of threads is equal to the number of cores.

Does Mathematica take advantage of hyper-threading?

My old (2007) desktop computer has an old Intel Core2 processor with 2 cores that does *not* support hyper-threading.  So the processor has 2 threads and 2 cores.  If I execute `$ProcessorCount` in Mathematica, it gives the output `2`.

However, some new processors (i.e., Intel i7 series) support hyper-threading.  For example, Intel's website says that the [i7-4790](http://ark.intel.com/products/80806/) has 8 threads and 4 cores.  If I were to execute `$ProcessorCount` on such a system, would the output be `4` or `8`?

Comment: I have an Intel® Core™ i7-4790K CPU @ 4.00GHz × 8 and `$ProcessorCount` gives `4`! :(

Comment: Of course. MMA does not "know" what's happening under the covers, the O/S scheduler handles that...

Comment: @ciao, well, it *can* get the information about how many physical cores are there if it needs to (at least under Linux-based OSes ... )

Comment: Great question.  Like @Mahdi, my Intel® Core™ i7-3820QM CPU has 2x hyper-threading, but `$ProcessorCount` gives `4`, the number of physical processors.

Comment: Is there any _standard_ code that shows exactly how many threads are used? I mean a code which exactly scales with number of cores.

Comment: Probable dupe of [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54553/mma-10-half-the-parallel-power-macs/54558#54558).  Simply put by Yes, default on v9 but only if you force it to on v10, and its impact is variable dependent on the calculation.  So the simple answer is try it and see if it works for your use case.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In *Mathematica* 10 or newer, as [pointed out](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54553/mma-10-half-the-parallel-power-macs/54558#54558) by Szabolcs, [`$ProcessorCount`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$ProcessorCount.html) will return the number of physical CPU cores, not the number of logical cores. Thus, on a system with 4 cores and 8 threads,

```
In[1]:= $ProcessorCount        

Out[1]= 4
```

Functionality which uses multiple kernels in parallel, for example [`ParallelEvaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelEvaluate.html) and friends, will then launch only 4 subkernels by default. This can be overriden by specifying an explicit number of kernels to start, say [`LaunchKernels[8]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LaunchKernels.html).

*Mathematica* also uses other kinds of parallelism, where [multiple threads](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3678/145) are running in parallel within the same kernel or library. The number of kernel threads, used e.g. by `Compile` and many image processing functions can also be changed and is controlled by

```
In[3]:= SystemOptions["ParallelOptions" -> "ParallelThreadNumber"]

Out[3]= {ParallelOptions -> {ParallelThreadNumber -> 4}}
```

Similarly, the maximum number of threads used by the Intel MKL library (for instance, when performing machine precision linear algebra computations) is

```
 In[4]:= SystemOptions["ParallelOptions" -> "MKLThreadNumber"]

 Out[4]= {ParallelOptions -> {MKLThreadNumber -> 4}}
```

Note that Intel [does not recommend](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-math-kernel-library-intel-mkl-intel-mkl-100-threading#5) using more threads in MKL than the number of physical cores.

Some functions may use all 8 hyperthreads in cases when performance will be increased (an example is `Det` and other linear algebra operations on exact numeric matrices).

Comment: Even in the old days of Pentium 4 with single CPUs with hyperthreading it has been useful to call LaunchKernels[2] to speed up Parallel* functions. However, until now there is no simple way to find out the number of logical processors. If an OpenMP environment variable like OMP_NUM_THREADS exists on the respective system, one could read it using GetEnvironment[].

Comment: I noticed that this has gone unaddressed in many of the hyperthreading related posts, but may be a common remark within recent times, so I request clarification instead of asking a new question on the following: please clarify, when you have 6 cores, how do you tell mathematics to use 4, hyperthreaded to 8? Generally, with Some smaller number of cores, but hyperthreaded (larger than the total number, for example, but it should not be exclusive to this requirement) without using the other remaining cores, is this even possible?

Comment: @CATrevillian Not from within the product, but the standard ways of configuring such things still apply, e.g. setting KMP_AFFINITY for MKL/OpenMP threads, or using tools like tasksel and numactl for pthreads.

Comment: @ilian ah okay, many thanks for this response. I’ll have to gain a new skill it seems! Quite incompetent when it comes to “real” computing, that is, outside of my limited knowledge of Mathematica and the WL. This is my first venture with a modern intel processor with more than 2 cores, hence the framing of my ask for clarification. You rock!