# Parallel Kernels and Hyperthreading

Tags: parallelization

I am using `Eigenvalues` a large number of times on a machine with 8 cores.  When I run `Eigenvalues` one time without any parallel implementation, the CPU usage hovers around 50%.  I suppose there is some parallelization built into the function.

Ideally, if I had enough memory, I would launch 8 cores and use ParallelMap: this gives 100% CPU usage.  However, I quickly run out of memory.

I do have enough memory to launch two cores and run in parallel.  However, now the CPU usage is 25%, so this is slower than simple sequential evaluation.  It seems using `ParallelMap` has excluded the in-built parallelization of `Eigenvalues`.

Is there any way I can get 2 parallel cores to run `Eigenvalues`, each one taking advantage of the parallelization already built into the function?  i.e. any way I can use the extra memory I have to get 100% out of my CPUs?

Comment: See [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84380/does-mathematica-take-advantage-of-hyper-threading-if-it-is-available/84436#84436) answer, in particular you may need to adjust `MKLThreadNumber` on the slave kernels. This may or may not result in any performance gain, note that Intel does not recommend the use of more threads than the number of **physical** cores.

Comment: The most effective technique I found is to open another kernel in the front end.  Then I am at 100% cpu usage.

Comment: For `Eigenvalues` to use 8 hyperthreads, just set  `SetSystemOptions["ParallelOptions" -> "MKLThreadNumber" -> 8];` and that will increase the reported CPU utilization. Similarly, If you want to use two kernels in parallel, `LaunchKernels[2]; ParallelEvaluate[
 SetSystemOptions["ParallelOptions" -> "MKLThreadNumber" -> 4]];` will override the default behavior where each slave kernel is single-threaded.

Comment: Your question reflects a common misconception about what SMT does and the mistaken idea that scheduler time corresponds to execution unit utilization. To put it briefly: `Eigenvalues` is working perfectly well without your additional attempts to parallelize it. If you measure the time taken to perform equivalent work, at best you will notice no difference, and more likely the attempt to use "100%" of the CPU will accomplish the task more slowly (i.e., less efficiently) than otherwise.

Comment: I did as instructed: diagonalize 4 matrices around dimensions 500,000.  In series required 1300 seconds.  In parallel (2 for each kernel) 1050.  I do not understand how having more cores in general would not make it more efficient to parallelize.

Comment: Do you actually have 8 cores, then, or 4 cores with 2 threads able to run simultaneously on each (i.e. SMT, "HyperThreading")? This makes a big difference and since you have mentioned HyperThreading in your question title I assumed the latter. But maybe it is actually the former situation. Also, if the matrices consist of something other than machine reals, the performance characteristics will be different. And if the matrices are small and independent, then perhaps it will be more efficient to manually parallelize it, because the parallelization will not be as effective for small matrices.

Comment: It also seems that `Eigenvalues` will not make the best parallelization choices by default. On my computer (with 4 cores), even for machine real matrices, there is the strange observation that 4 MKL threads results in slightly better parallelization than 2, but 3 threads is noticeably superior to either of these. In general one can expect that the result may be constrained as much by available memory bandwidth as it is by the resources of the CPU.