# Mathematica does not recognize all CPU kernels/cores

Tags: performance-tuning, parallelization, kernel, system-performance

I am using Ubuntu 22 and Mathematica 13. According to the description of my laptop I should have **four** CPU cores, as seen in the following screenshot:

[image]

However, Mathematica only seems to recognize **two** kernels when attempting any parallel computation (see the following screenshot).

[image]

Am I seeing something wrong, or is there a way to tell Mathematica to use all four kernels?

Many thanks!

Comment: You have two physical cores - and four logical "cores" because of hyperthreading.
Read here: https://support.wolfram.com/27877?src=mathematica 
_"By design, Mathematica automatically launches subkernels equal to the number of physical CPU cores."_

Comment: It also says: _"To override this setting, use the LaunchKernels[n] function, where n is an integer indicating the number of local subkernels to launch."_

Comment: And here is your CPU specs which indeed show only 2 physical cores: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/88193/intel-core-i56200u-processor-3m-cache-up-to-2-80-ghz/specifications.html. Note that Intel likes advertising HyperThreading as doubling the number of cores, but security paranoid folks (e.g. OpenBSD) recommend to disable it to protect from side-channel attacks.

Comment: Since when having a support ticket answering a question is reason to close it? This could be consider a [duplicate of this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/105437/10397) but I don't see how the *Wolfram Support* argument holds