# Why is this parallel notebook not maxing out the available memory and processors?

Tags: performance-tuning, parallelization, distributions

I've searched many questions about parallel processing here, and they are either specialized or over my head. I run the following parallel notebook on an 8 core EC2 instance. The average memory usage is ~40% of 32GB and the CPU utilization is ~50%. Using "CoarsestGrained" does not help. Why is it not maxing out the system capacity?

```
Remove["Global`*"];
LaunchKernels[];
mccount = 10^6;
cyclesperday = RandomVariate[LogNormalDistribution[-0.9, 1.3], 635554];
samplemanycyclesper5years = 
  ParallelTable[
   Total[RandomChoice[cyclesperday, 1826]], {100*mccount}];
cycledatatofit = Partition[samplemanycyclesper5years, 100];
samplecycledistributions = 
  ParallelTable[
   EstimatedDistribution[cycledatatofit[[i]], 
    LogNormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]]], {i, 1, mccount}];
samplecycledistributions[[1]]
```

Comment: 50% CPU utilization probably means quite exactly 100% CPU utilization for numeric purposes. For example, macOS measures only 100% if hyperthreading is used. But hyperthreading is contraproductive for numerical operations so Mathematica deactivates it. See also [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/84436/38178).

Comment: [Also related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54553/38178).

Comment: `LaunchKernels@8`